# TCP/IP Stack in Windows Server 2008 vs Windows 7 Ultimate

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-7, tcpip

Does anyone know the *details* as to the differences between the TCP/IP stack in Windows Server 2008 (Standard) vs Windows 7 Ultimate?

This question pertains to TCP/IP ONLY.

I know that Windows 7 and Server 2008 have a unified driver model -- so the driver portion of the TCP/IP stack is, theoretically the same.

On precisely the same hardware, supporting a heavily loaded TCP/IP app, will the Server 2008 TCP/IP stack offer any advantages over a out of the box Windows 7 Ultimate box?

I have heard many (vauge) insinuations as to advantages of the server's stack, but have never seen anything concrete like: Server supports a XYZ megabyte flux capacitor buffer, while Windows 7 only supports a 2 mb flux capacitor buffer...

A link to a tech doc or site outlining the differences would be awesome.

Comment: Just to clear some things up, Windows Server 2008 (sp1) is comparable to Windows Vista SP1... so for Windows 7, the server version it equals is Server 2008 R2...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a doc on server but boy, geek technical info for 7 is as rare as common sense at my company...

TCP/IP on 2008 [link text](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd379523(WS.10).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit olique, but in Windows XP there was a hard limit of 10 client connections. I imagine there is some similar restriction in 7.

Comment: Actually, no. The limit is only for 10 half-open connections, not total connections.
Additionally, we need to define a 'connection'. Whether a machine is listening on a port or simply connecting to one are two different things.
It appears that the limit is much lower on the former as it is on the latter.